# Wordpress: Need help to customize .js code to call out specific dynamic class within Visual Composer

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, wordpress

The site in question is [www.topcatsmusic.com](http://www.topcatsmusic.com)

At the bottom ive coded a player which utilizes js. Beneath the player Ive included a dynamic slider to display .jpg files or album covers. As it is now, Ive been using a simple href tag to send to external soundcloud source.

However, the plugin allows you to make API calls to en-queue the song within the player instead of sending to new window, outside source.

Sample API usage:

```js
ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").getTrack("https://soundcloud.com/top-cats/treee-city-fzpz-pines?in=top-cats/sets/releases");
```

Custom JS file in use "Clickfunction.js"

```js
  $('.ult-item-wrap a').click(function(e) {
    var sound = $(this).attr('href');
    ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").addTracks(sound);
    ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").removeTracks(0, 1);
    ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").addTracks(sound);
    alert(ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").getAllTracks());
    return false;
  });
```

So, if I load the JS file using the

```js
<script> </script>
```

within my header - what do I need to do to customize this code so I can identify which song to load based on the custom class assigned to each image?

Comment: The Website is offline. Can you provide a working link?

Comment: Thanks Radscheit! Ive been working on it so that may be a temporary thing.. Should be up. Try now if youd like!

Comment: feel free to recheck website - all functionality is now working. The only thing thats not "working" is the player wont switch to display playlist mode as advertised / displayed in the toneden player SDK on github. 

I also saw that they were having some compatibility issues with Chrome so they removed the Visualization.. Im wondering if that affected the playlist mode as well.

Comment: https://github.com/ToneDen/toneden-sdk

here is a link to the documentation if anyone is curious

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code a little and see if that works:

```
jQuery( document ).on('click', '.ult-item-wrap a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sound = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").addTracks(sound);
    ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").removeTracks(0, 1);
    ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").addTracks(sound);
    alert(ToneDen.player.getInstanceByDom("#player").getAllTracks());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Oserk! I will try out the suggestions as mentioned and share the results / my pain if still not troubleshooting correctly. Feedback is greatly appreciated <3

Answer (score 0):

Woo hoo! Got it to work. Thanks for the help from everyone. Here is the code I ended up adding to my images to en-queue. Hopefully this method proves to be helpful for any other bands / blogs / musicians wanting to use this cool toneden player.

```
<span data-href="https://soundcloud.com/top-cats/autumn-keys-long-shadows?in=top-cats/sets/releases" class="toneden_song"><img src="YOUR DIRECTORY HERE/long-shadow-cover-150x150.jpg"></span>
```

Comment: The main issue was changing the href to a data-href and making sure to add a specific class to my images